# How to connect database from cPanel to Desktop in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, python-3.x, cpanel

I am making an application in python - and need to connect to a web server database from the desktop.
 
How can I do this.

example:

if my site is **xyz.com** it's ip is **123.134.121.136** and my database name is **xyz_code** and name is **xyz_alibaba** and password is *!@#!#1&#a#@*

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

s_h = "123.134.121.136:3306"
s_u = "xyz_alibaba"
s_p = "!@#!#1&#a#@"
s_d = "softwar1_codexyz_code"

s_cn = mdb.connect(s_h, s_u, s_p, s_d)

if s_cn :
    print "ok"
else:
    print "no"
```

When I run this code it shows an `unknown loaclhost` error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please show the full trace of the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your ISP IP in remote mysql host access list? And enable port 3306 in your server firewall.

Answer (score 0):

you choose wrong way to connect !!!

it's the code :

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="123.134.121.136",  
                     port=3306,  
                     user="xyz_alibaba",     
                     passwd="!@#!#1&#a#@", 
                     db="xyz_code")
```